# How to use angular js Filters Inside a controler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

How can we use angular js filters inside a controller. For example if I want to use unique filter from angular-ui

It works fine when I use it inside  html with ng repeat

```
"data-ng-repeat="orders in orderList | unique: 'submission_Date'"
```

but when I try to use it inside my controller then it is not working properly

```
($filter('unique')($scope.orderList ,$scope.orderList.submission_Date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the second argument as a string:

```
$filter('unique')($scope.orderList, 'submission_Date');
```

Also, you can dependency inject a specific filter by appending the word "Filter" to it. Then you can use the filter function directly, which looks nicer:

```
uniqueFilter($scope.orderList, 'submission_Date');
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could inject specific filters.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is the same as in the template, and in this case should be a string.

```
$filter('unique')($scope.orderList ,"submission_Date")
```